What is the probability that an intersection of tensor of linear spaces?
Denote by $Gr(n,k)$ the Grassmannian over q-dimensional finite space $\mathbb{F}_q$.
For a subspace $V \in Gr(n_1n_2,v)$, What is the probability that for two random subspaces $U_1 \in Gr(n_1,u_1)$ and $U_2 \in Gr(n_2,u_2)$ the dimension $\dim(U \cap V) \geq k)$
, where $$U = U_1 \otimes \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n_2} + \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n_1}\otimes U_2.$$
I want to know the upper bound of this.
Although I calculated it, I only got the following inequality
$$ Pr(\dim(U \cap V) \geq k)) \leq \binom{\dim V}{k} \frac{\binom{n_1 n_2 - k}{\dim U - k}}{\binom{n_1}{u_1}\binom{n_2}{u_2}}.$$
If $n_1,n_2 \to \infty$, then this upper bound exceeds $1$!!
Please tell me how to obtain more tight bound.

I considered the case of $u_1 \propto n_1$ and $u_2 \propto n_2$.
